# How do I compile a file with Java code on goDaddy hosting and upload it to my domain

Tags: java, web-hosting

I have a GoDaddy hosting subscription and have been able to alter the source code of the webpage by viewing file manager then editing and saving a .html doc. I would like to program the page in Java, though, so I can implement what we have been learning in my computer science course outside of the coding sandbox.

According to one question I researched -- [another user's question on GoDaddy and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017467/how-to-deploy-java-web-application-war-through-my-godaddys-cpanel/22522568#22522568) -- GoDaddy does not support Java, but I am not trying to use the more complex functions. Most of it can be achieved using JavaScript.

```html
<body> <script> System.out.print("simple things such as this inside script do not seem to be compatible with the html files in file manager but it may just be me") </script> </body>
```

I apologize if anyone is offended by my sad knowledge of coding but I am trying my best to learn, thanks for reading and for the help.
Edit: Thank you for the clarity, I realize that Java and JavaScript are two separate languages but there are some similarities in what their functions are at base level so that is why I mentioned interchanging the two.

Answer (score 2):

If your hosting provider doesn't support Java, you can't run Java code on your site.  If what you want can be done in JavaScript instead, feel free to do that, but it doesn't change the situation with Java.

In addition to being different languages, Java and JavaScript have different roles in web development:  Java is typically used on the server to dynamically generate the HTML that gets sent to the browser, whereas JavaScript runs in the browser (and hence doesn't need any special support from the server).

(It's also possible to run Java in the browser using applets, but that's discouraged these days for security reasons, and it's possible to run JavaScript on a server using Node.js, but that's more advanced than your current skill level and I don't think it's what you're looking for.)

If you want to try out Java web development but you don't have a real website that supports it, you can run [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) on your own computer.  That'll give you a small website running on your own computer (with a URL like `http://localhost:8080/`) where you can deploy Java web applications.